# Cannot find login button id on HTML

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to use VBA for web scraping. The email and password info are being input but to click the login button my code is running through an error. When i click inspect on the button this is what i get
[image]

This is my code

```
Sub DMS_Login()

Dim ie As Object Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Sheet1 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://app.dmsprojects.net/login"

Do While .Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents Loop
 
ie.document.getElementById("mat-input-0").Value = "Username" 
ie.document.getElementById("mat-input-1").Value = "Password" 
ie.document.forms("login").submit

Do While .Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents Loop

End With Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Please include exact error messages and indicate which line(s) produces the error(s)

Answer (score 0):

You can try combining a css selector list of the target element class with the aria-label attribute and its value

```
ie.document.querySelector(".submit-button[aria-label=LOGIN]").click
```